# Concerns about Migrating from IIS6 to IIS8

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8, iis-8.5

We would like to migrate our websites from IIS 6 to IIS 8.

I would like to understand if I could face any "additional" compatibility issues when we migrate to IIS 8/8.5 as opposed to IIS 7.

Comment: Um... test first?  Why would you migrate *anything* without doing a trial run first?

Answer (score 1):

I've just done this when moving sites to a new virtual server.

Advice is to go slow!

1 - Classic ASP is not supported by default so you have to add it from the IIS UI and set it up how you need it.

2 - Make sure you have the correct version of .NET installed and ready to go..again you can install straight from the UI using the NuGet thing.

3 - Make sure your sites have the correct version of .NET assigned to their pool. .NET 1 apps wont work on 4.5 for instance. Im not an expert of .NET versioning as I jumped in at version 3.5 but anything prior to 3.5 will I believe need to have that specific version installed or work done to update it.

4 - PHP although installable from the NuGet UI can be tricky...it worked first time for me on one site but then another one wouldnt run any PHP files. There are lots of help documents about though.

Apart from that the whole thing is easier, has proper URL rewriting built in and is a better option than II6 in almost all regards... if you can stand server 2012 that is.